# Multiplying in VBA returning zeros

Tags: vba

I typed following code in VBA and it returns zeros?

I'm trying to calculate the revenue in VBA. Salgspris is the price, and AntalsoglteVare is Nr of goods sold. I try to multiply them in VBA using following code, but it returns zeros.

```
Sub Revenue()

Dim SalgsPris As Double 
Dim AntalSolgteVare As Integer
Dim Revenue As Double 

Range("a2").Activate

Do

SalgsPris = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value
AntalSoglteVare = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Value

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6) = SalgsPris * AntalSolgteVare

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate

Loop Until ActiveCell = ""

End Sub
```

Comment: If you add `Option Explicit` at the top of your module (to *every* module) it will fix this problem. Hint - you need to check your spelling...

Comment: Put a breakpoint on that multiplication line and see what the values are in those variables in your `Locals` pane. Should be a snap to debug this in VBE.

Comment: This appears to be work better suited for a formula. You can make the cells contain formulea that perform the multiplication. If you put your data in to a table and add the formula as a calculated field it will automatically copy down to all rows.